# C# - Load simple Excel file into a datatable using FileUpload control

Tags: c#, excel, upload, datatable, populate

I'm trying to figure out how to populate a datatable with data from and Excel file that's been uploaded using the FileUpload control. Does anyone know of a tutorial to do this?

I haven't been able to find anything on Google, maybe using wrong search terms?

Comment: There are 3 separate tasks here: upload excel file, parse it and then put the data to db. You _must_ be able to find solutions for all three problems. And it's _not_ surprising you cannot find solution for this sequence of actions all together: it needs more than and article to create and describe such thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [LinqToExcel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) to parse data. Then, when you have the data in memory, put it into a database whichever way you prefer.

Comment: Thanks! But... Don't think this would work. Not allowed to incorporate third party DLL's in project... I'm going to use it in my personal projects tough! LOL

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an alternative way? This is vb.net but the same objects.  I do this sort of thing all the time.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/7337ad66-7673-425b-97ff-41adbd8a68e9

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1255191.aspx/1

It is C#, using OLEDB so third party libraries are not needed, and a DataTable is populated with the excel data.

These are my google search terms: "upload excel file to datatable c#"